# Experts should vote more often to help beginners determine good answers

Tags: discussion, voting

I'm starting to learn solidity and Ethereum SE has started to be one of my main sources of information. I've found good answers here and I'm very thankful for that.

However, it can be hard to determine good answers when a lot of them have **literally 0 votes**. Is this because no answers are good?

Peer reviewing and validation is very important, and newcomers and the whole community would benefit of experts reviewing, voting and commenting on answers.

Comment: Sometimes there are too many questions and not enough participants willing to answer or vote. Also the search is not good at finding existing answers so we have many duplicates, or old questions without updates that will make them useful for newer versions. Also many questions are poorly written, the title is bad, others once are answered but the they weren't marked as resolved. All of that causes low engagement.